# New user does not have a Postfix `Maildir` directory?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, mail-server, email-server

I am attempting to have multiple user accounts, each capable of receiving their own mail in their own `Maildir` directory. When I add a new user account however, no `Maildir` directory structure is created.

I have been researching online and from what I have read, the `Maildir` directory structure should be created on receipt of the first inbound mail. When I attempt sending mail to a certain user account, and then use `mail` as that user, I get the message `No mail for user`, and no mail structure is created.

I attempted creating the structure myself, adding `/Maildir/new/` and `/Maildir/tmp`. Once created, `mail` now returns

```
Cannot open mailbox /home/user/Maildir: Is a directory
No mail for user
```

This makes me suspect the issue could be between postfix expecting an mbox format (file) instead of Maildir format (directory). Though postfix's `main.cf` file does have `home_mailbox = Maildir/` set.

I suspect the issue could possibly be due to problems in my setting up of postfix `virtual_aliases`, though I'm not entirely sure.

If anyone has any suggestions or thoughts as to what the issue could be, input would be appreciated. For someone who has done this before, what general process do you follow when adding a new postfix user? I think an answer to this may help point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you using system accounts or virtual accounts for Postfix?

Comment: I know I never could get `mail` to use `sendmail` properly (because of localhost problems) for outgoing SMTP.  I had to use `msmtp` to send anything.  I don't know how that affects incoming, but `mail` can be a headache.  P.S. Make that a file not a dir.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I am trying to have mail sent to system accounts. I have `virtual_aliases` set in postfix - is this what you mean by 'virtual accounts' ? To my understanding, `virtual_aliases` should be sending to system accounts.

Comment: @J.Cravens thankyou for the thoughts. What do you mean in your 'P.S make that a file not a dir' ? Are you recommending I change the Maildir/ directory to a file instead ? Will this allow the correct Maildir/ directory structure to be created ?

Comment: Yes, the 'Maildir' is the file that `mail` opens.  It's usually `/var/spool/mail/username` where `username` is a file.  That will solve '/home/user/Maildir: Is a directory'.